# Игра не запускает мод если в корневой папке нету dll с модом

Tags: c++, разработка-игр, dll

У меня непонятная проблема. Я начинающий моддер, писал свои моды для игр на С++ и инжектил их в игру через dll файлы, с помощью инжектора. Но у меня возникает проблема, если я убираю дллки из папки с игрой, то игра запускается без них (без всяких ошибок), несмотря на то что я инжекчу их в игру с помощью инжектора в котором указываю путь до dll файла, но если я добавлю dll файлы в папку с игрой то все будет работать, почему так происходит? Хочу уточнить что путь до dll верный и с инжектором нет проблем, мне кажется что это как-то связано с самой dll, но я не знаю из-за чего это происходит.
Я пробовал внутри DLLMain добавлять функцию SetDLLDirectory для обозначения пути хранения dll файлов, но это не сработало
Также хочу уточнить что если я убираю dll из папки с игрой, то она находится в папке с инжектором, проблема в том что игра не видит длл если нет ее в папке с игрой, даже если инжектить, она просто запускается без dll и работает как обычно

Comment: Какой инжектор? Думаете он один?

Comment: О чем вы? В смысле он один? Инжектор это программа которая внедряет вашу длл в другую программу, применяется для создания читов или модов

Comment: В смысле покажите код инжектора, или дайте название.

Comment: Как я и говорил проблема не в инжекторе, я забыл добавить что есть дллки которые инжектор загружает в игру, даже если они не находятся в папке с игрой и все работает. Но есть у меня одна длл которая не работает если не находится в папке с игрой. Я бы показал код инжектора но в нем много файлов, да и думаю что проблема все таки не в нем. Все что мне нужно это просто теории о том в чем может быть проблема, с остальным я сам разберусь

Comment: *"проблема не в инжекторе"* Обычно на это отвечают, что если бы вы знали, в чем проблема, вас бы тут не было.

Comment: ну а как вы можете объяснить то что 95% длл загружаются в игру, а оставшиеся 5% нет (цифры условные)? Очевидно, как по мне, что проблема в самой длл

Comment: @noob_proger Но требования, предъявляемые инжектором к загружаемой dll - разные.  Например, проверьте требования к размещению сторонних dll (vcrt, ... ), от которых зависит ваша dll.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду зависимости для dll? То есть если нету необходимых длл в папке с инжектором, например Winmm.dll, то игра не будет видеть загружаемую длл? Или как это работает, можете пожалуйста поподробнее? В первые слышу про требования к инжектору, где можно про них почитать?

Comment: Стандартный поиск зависимых DLL: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order   Путь к загружаемой dll в списке поиска не фигурирует. Некоторые инжекторы могут модифицировать PATH, некоторые -нет. Читайте инструкцию к инжектору.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблема была в том что у меня были 2 дллки в которых были циркулирующие зависимости ( то есть они обе зависели друг от друга), после фикса этого бага, проблема исчезла